# NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore is unavailable - watchOS 2

Tags: ios, swift, icloud, watchos-2, watchos

I am getting this error when using NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore in my watchOS 2 app:

```
    NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore is unavailable
```

This happens whenever I try to use iCloud key-value storage on watchOS. Does anybody have a solution?

Comment: Looks like my answer is right, so you can mark it as the right, so others could see it

Answer (score 1):

Found some strange information in my Xcode 7.3:

As you can see apple saying that watchOs version available from 2.0 to 2.1 (I have the same issue to yours with watchOS 2.2)

[image]

Comment: Would be nice to have someone test on watchOS 2.0 or 2.1 then

Comment: Getting this error with Xcode 8.2.1, watchOS 3.1.  Is there a solution?

Comment: Same problem with 3.1.3.  Works on the sim not the watch.  Document storage doesn't work either.

Comment: Why is Apple trying to deprecate WatchConnectivity framework and pushing us to CloudKit if something so basic as NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore is not available!??!?!?!